# Every semisimple Lie algebra is rigid

Tags: lie-algebras, zariski-topology

I am trying to understand why every (complex, finite-dimensional) semisimple Lie algebra is rigid. I understand there is a cohomological proof, but I would like to understand a more direct argument, namely via the Killing form.

Definition: $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ acts on the set of all $n$-dimensional Lie algebra laws $\lambda$ by $(g\cdot\lambda)(x,y)=g(\lambda(g^{-1}x,g^{-1}y))$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{C}^n$. We can denote the orbit under this action by $O(\lambda)$. If $O(\lambda)$ is open in the Zariski topology, then the Lie algebra with law $\lambda$ is called rigid.

Now, I want to prove that every semisimple Lie algebra is rigid. The argument seems to be that "Killing form being non-degenerate is an open condition" (see [1]).

One can identify an $n$-dimensional Lie algebra (given a basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$) with law $\lambda$ by its structure constants $\lambda(e_i,e_j)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}C_{ij}^ke_k$, so we can view $\lambda$ as the vector $(C_{ij}^k)\in\mathbb{C}^{n^3}$. So, I (believe I) want to show that the set
$\{a=(a_1,...,a_{n^3})\in\mathbb{C}^{n^3}:\text{ the Lie algebra law corresponding to $a$ is semisimple} \}$ is open in the Zariski topology. How do I do this?

We have
$\{(a_1,...,a_{n^3})\in\mathbb{C}^{n^3}:\text{ the corresponding Lie algebra law is semisimple} \}=\{a=(a_1,...,a_{n^3})\in\mathbb{C}^{n^3}:\text{ the corresponding Killing form } \kappa_a \text{ is non-degenerate} \}$.

So I need to find a set of polynomials in $n^3$ variables such that its zeros are precisely the vectors $a$ where $\kappa_a$ is non-degenerate.
This is where I fail. I suspect that these polynomials will be very similar to the Killing form itself (like, the Killing form viewed as a polynomial for fixed $x$ and $y$), but I cannot create these polynomials.

Moreover, I don't know what to do next. So suppose I can show that the set $A$ of all semisimple Lie algebra laws is open, how do I show that each seperate orbit $O(\mu)$ (which consists of the Lie algebras isomorphic to $\mu$) is open?

[1] Yu. A.  Neretin, An estimate of the number of parameters defining an n-dimensional algebra, Math. USSR Izvestiya, Vol. 30 (1988), No. 2

Comment: Once you've fixed your basis, you can write out the Killing form as an n by n matrix with coefficients in the structure constants. For your first question, is it as simple as asking for the determinant of this to be non-zero?

Comment: You're right! Thank you very much, I did not think about that! So $\{(a_1,...,a_{n^3})\}\in\mathbb{C}^{n^3}$: the corresponding Lie algebra law is semisimple$\}=\{(a_1,...,a_{n^3})\}\in\mathbb{C}^{n^3}:$ the determinant of the corresponding matrix is nonzero $\}$. And the latter set is clearly open in the Zariski topology. Thank you!

Comment: That the set of semisimple algebras is open does not mean that semisimple algebras are rigid. It could well be that there are semisimple algebras do have deformations, but that all the algebras it deforms to are themselves also semisimple. You need the orbits to be open, and that is quite different.

Answer (score 3):

The "more direct way" with the Killing form is not enough as Mariano already explained. 
I think, the natural way to see that every semisimple Lie algebra is rigid, over a field of characteristic zero, is indeed via $2$-cocycles for the adjoint representation. One could also argue that this is the most direct way, because a formal deformation of a Lie algebra $L$ directly leads to $2$-cocycles.

This is due to Gerstenhaber, see [On the Deformation of Rings and Algebras](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970484?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents): A formal one-parameter deformation of $L$ is a power series
$$
[g,h]_t := [g,h] + \sum_{k\ge 1}\phi_k(g,h)t^k
$$
such that the Jacobi identity for $[ \;, \;]_t$ holds, with $2$-cochains
$\phi_k\in C^2(L,L)$ and $g,h\in L$. The Jacobi identity implies in particular, that the maps $\phi_k$ are $2$-cocycles for the adjoint representation, i.e., 
$$
\phi_k\in Z^2(L,L)
$$
Two formal deformations of $L$ are called equivalent, if
the resulting Lie algebras are isomorphic. The equivalence classes are represented by a cohomology class from $H^2(L,L)$. Now
$L$ is called *formally rigid*, if every formal deformation
is trivial.
If $H^2(L,L)=0$, then $L$ is obviously formally rigid. The Whitehead Lemma says that every semisimple Lie algebra over characteristic zero satisfies $H^2(L,L)=0$, hence is formally rigid.

Gerstenhaber and Schack proved that *formally rigid* is equivalent to *geometrically rigid*, which means that $L$ has open orbit in the "variety of all Lie algebra structures of dimension $\dim (L)$".